# Safari 10 CSS.supports('display', 'contents') returns true even though it is not supported?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

According to CanIUse.com, `display:contents` has some support across browsers.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents

I would like to enable the feature in browsers which support and disable the feature in browsers which do not support.

So, I use `CSS.supports('display', 'contents');` to determine if it is supported or not. In IE11, I have to make an extra check because `CSS` is not supported.

However, my expectation is that in Safari11, it should return `true`, and in Safari10, it should return `false`. Instead what happens is both return `true`. The UI clearly looks correct in 11, however in 10, there are undesirable effects because `display: contents` does not actually work, so my patch-class is not applied & UI looks wrong. This is confirmed to be caused by the invalid feature detection.

I searched for solutions to detect Safari10 (and not Safari11), but unable to find anything that works.

How can I tell from JavaScript accurately wether or not the feature is supported / I am in Safari 10?

Comment: Have you tried `CSS.supports("(display: contents;)")`? The API may be buggy and that alternate form works sometimes when the two-parameter form doesn't.

Comment: [also this](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/safari-display-contents-bug) - *edit* oh well 11.1 is supposedly when it started working

Comment: @pointy thanks for responding!

`CSS.supports('(display:contents')` returns `true` in Safari 10 and Safari 11.

`CSS.supports('(display:contents;)')` returns `false` in Safari 11. Did not check 10.

I tried with and without space, as well.

Comment: Hmm, I got this 

`const isSafari10 = window.RTCDataChannel === undefined && (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);`

This seems to work as "expected" in 10 and 11. Now i have to check all other browsers.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the semicolon in the syntax, sorry

Comment: Also, while I don't as a rule suggest libraries as solutions, it might be interesting to look into whether Modernizr has something to detect this, and either try it out or else just look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
@supports (display: contents) and (not (-webkit-flow-from: main)) {
  /**/
}
```

the `display: contents`-check only raises a false flag up to Safari 11, so I've been scrolling through the CSS values on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) and found [CSS Regions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions), which is only supported by MS browsers up to Edge 18 (the last version that doesn't use Chrome's rendering engine) and Safari versions up to 11.
IE doesn't support `@supports` and Edge doesn't support `-webkit-flow-from`.

I haven't tested this, by the way, since I don't own any Apple products. If someone could do that, that would be great.

Comment: This query appears to work well in my preliminary tests. Good idea!