# Check for browser support of display: contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if the browser supports `display: contents` and then remove certain elements (f. e. via [unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)) if it does not?

I would like to change the following structure …

```
<header class="ifDisplayContents">
    <div id="logo">…</div>
    <nav id="nav">…</div>
</header>
<main class="ifDisplayContents">
    <div id="content1">…</div>
    <div id="content2">…</div>
    <div id="content3">…</div>
</main>
```

… to …

```
<div id="logo">…</div>
<nav id="nav">…</div>
<div id="content1">…</div>
<div id="content2">…</div>
<div id="content3">…</div>
```

… for browsers not supporting `display: contents`.
It can be via jquery, but it doesn't have to be.

Background information: it is used to be able to keep a good semantic structure and still position the sub-elements in one collective grid, excluding as few old browsers as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers typically reject applying invalid style property values. So if you set the display value on a created element then check what that property returns they should match if supported.

```js
function isvalidDisplay(val){
   var el = document.createElement('div');
   el.style.display = val;
   return el.style.display === val;
}

['inline','block','foobar','contents'].forEach(v=> console.log(v,isvalidDisplay(v)))
```

Note that certain properties that use color or dimensions other than pixels are more complex than this due to internal conversions done to them

Editing from the questioner – the overall solution:

```
function isvalidDisplay(val){
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.style.display = val;
    return el.style.display === val;
}
if (!isvalidDisplay('contents')){
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('ifDisplayContents');
    while(el.length) {
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        while(el[ 0 ].firstChild) fragment.appendChild(el[ 0 ].firstChild);
        el[ 0 ].parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, el[ 0 ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot! I have added the working code snippet, matching my example, to your question. I hope this is o.k. Feel free to remove it if you don't like it.

Comment: Think it's better just to answer the "check for support" part which I think was your main hurdle. The unwrapping is fairly common and straightforward.

Comment: O.k., thanks, for me the latter was not so easy either ;-) But my edit was not approved anyway ("It is only visible to you until it's been approved by trusted community members").

Answer (score 1):

There is the `CSS.supports` DOM API which you can use for this:

```js
const isSupported = CSS.supports('display', 'contents');
```

If the `CSS.supports` DOM API is not supported by your browser (for example IE), `display: contents` would probably not be either.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/supports)

Comment: Thank you very much! I like this solution approach, it is short and clear. I have read that some browsers may react to this incorrectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072444/safari-10-css-supportsdisplay-contents-returns-true-even-though-it-is-not I'm unsure if this is really a problem and if it could possibly apply to the other solution. What do you think?